# Designing syntax tree derived node classes

Tags: c#, parsing, trees

Let's say I have an abstract `Node` class and `BinaryOperation` class derived from `Node` and three classes `IntegerConstant`, `RealConstant` and `CharacterConstant` also derived from `Node`.

The general design for the `BinaryOperation` class would look like this:

```
public class BinaryOperation : Node
{
    public Node Operand1 { get; private set; }
    public Node Operand2 { get; private set; }
    //...
}
```

I also have parsing methods for those classes, each of them returning given type. So `IsIntegerConstant()` is of type `IntegerConstant` and so on.

Now when parsing an operand in expression I could easily check the type like this:

```
Node operand1 = IsIntegerConstant() ??
                IsRealConstant() ??
                IsCharacterConstant();
```

[However C# does not allow that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974664/null-coalescing-issue-with-abstract-base-derived-classes). Because compiler cannot determine the type of the expression in `operand1` assignment. What should I do? Should I make all of the parsing methods return type `Node` or cast each method to `Node`. Or maybe create separate `BinaryOperation` class members for each of the operand types?

Comment: Don't all you need to do is cast _one_ call in the nullable to `Node` for the type inference to work? Annoying, but better than changing your design substantially to make the syntax a little cleaner.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. But seriously this makes the code really ugly, while I it will be used a lot in the parsing methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What should I do? Should I make all of the parsing methods return type Node or cast each method to Node.

I'd suggest adding, to use here in your example, a more general operand-parsing wrapper that returns `Node` whose implementation internally determines the type of the operand perhaps using such cascading.

> Or maybe create separate BinaryOperation class members for each of the operand types?

No, don't do that!  This seems like class explosion to me.  You'd need a subclass for each left operand subclass X a subclass for each right operand subclass — a whole matrix of classes, for what I can only see as little-to-no value.

---

What do you do if all including the last `IsCharacterConstant()` fails?  It seems that `operand1` becomes null in that case, ignoring the parse input  — rather than getting some useful error.  You might try:

```
Node operand1 = IsIntegerConstant() ??
                IsRealConstant() ??
                IsCharacterConstant() ??
                ReportError("... this operator must have a constant left operand ...");
```

where `ReportError` has declared return type of Node, thus satisfying the C# inference algorithm.

---

I'm not familiar with this parsing technique; it seems very specific, are you thinking it will support your long term needs?  Do you not support parenthesis or nested binary operations?

I ask because the question of type inference ugliness becomes moot if a more general parsing method is needed anyway — as a more general method might parse an operand to a `Node`, making this cascading not so broadly visible across your code base, if not eliminating it.

Comment: This parses postfix expressions. When it comes to null-checking, I didn't mention it but I check it just after assigning.